# How to understand MSDN documentation?

Tags: msdn

When I used to use VB 6 in my high school MSDN was just fantastic, I never looked anywhere else for help. Then came .NET and online MSDN and whatnot, and there were no longer any practical examples of anything. I slowly started to avoid MSDN and now when I search something on Google I straight away add `-msdn` in there.

If you take a simple example of [ArrayList count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.count(v=VS.71).aspx) there is nothing mentioning that count has to be used like this:

```cs
ArrayList tmpArray = new ArrayList();
tmpArray.Add("something");
LabelCount.text = tmpArray.Count;
```

The way MSDN has it is actually really helpful if you have a basic idea of what member variables are etc. But if you are new to C# in general, you would be completely lost.

PHP documentation is so neat! A simple [strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) has a neat depiction of what are the return values, parameters for function etc, plus the comment section has lots of users giving out so many valuable usage example of `strlen` which I find really amazingly relevant and helpful.

Is there a way to look at things and understand in MSDN? How do you guys refer MSDN?

Comment: Granted they don't have the examples up front. Make sure you're looking at the most recent version though (you linked to .NET 1.1). Switch the version to v4, and see the difference.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010. So I'd guess that its v4 anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft's documentation does not have the beauty and simplicity that linux `man` or `info` has, but still, it's very comprehensive. You need to know that it's not tutorials in most cases, it's reference documentation, that assumes you already know how to use that function.

Comment: okay so how or where do I need to check If I need a simple usage tutorial for this?

Comment: Well, probably on the web or in books. Microsoft provides some tutorials and there are simple examples for each function/

Comment: Worst-case SOing? I would argue (and fight to my death bed) that SO questons and answers are my primary "documentation" for simple code sample usages. Besides, the majority of the time there's explanations, critiques, and fixes to code samples.